# GUI Designer not running on IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, intellij-idea, designer

I'm learning how to make GUIs on IntelliJ but the frame I make doesn't appear when I run the program. I've tried making the main folder a source root, changing the settings and adding a bit of code but it doesn't want to work. Right now all Im trying to make is a panel with a button, that's it. I'd appreciate if someone could help, thanks :)

This is the code, I don't know why it's getting formated all weird, sorry.

public class Game extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel panel;
private JButton button1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setContentPane(new Game().panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize JPanel and JButton and add them on JFrame using **"add"** method. For example:

```java
public class Game extends JFrame {
  private static JPanel panel;
  private static JButton button1;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    panel = new JPanel();
    button1 = new JButton("Test");
    panel.add(button1);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have the same problem I was having. I just needed to add some code to the main class.

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new Game();
            frame.setSize(300,300);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
```